# Issue customizing y-axis max on brush chart in ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have a brushed chart with two datasets with vastly different values. I am trying to change the max of the y-axis for both datasets. I am successful in doing so in the brush chart line, but not in the main chart.
Currently, the y-axis on the left corresponding to the price graph does not have a max value of 1, which is what I expected my code to do. It does however work on the brush chart line.

I am at loss at how to solve this issue.

See an example of my issue in the snippet below.

```js
const pricedata = [{
    "x": 1697842800000,
    "y": 0.834
  },
  {
    "x": 1697929200000,
    "y": 0.835
  },
  {
    "x": 1698015600000,
    "y": 0.831
  },
  {
    "x": 1698102000000,
    "y": 0.821
  },
  {
    "x": 1698188400000,
    "y": 0.768
  },
  {
    "x": 1698274800000,
    "y": 0.751
  },
  {
    "x": 1698361200000,
    "y": 0.756
  },
  {
    "x": 1698447600000,
    "y": 0.766
  },
  {
    "x": 1698534000000,
    "y": 0.75
  },
  {
    "x": 1698624000000,
    "y": 0.751
  },
  {
    "x": 1698710400000,
    "y": 0.761
  },
  {
    "x": 1698796800000,
    "y": 0.722
  },
  {
    "x": 1698883200000,
    "y": 0.705
  },
  {
    "x": 1698969600000,
    "y": 0.72
  },
  {
    "x": 1699056000000,
    "y": 0.736
  },
  {
    "x": 1699142400000,
    "y": 0.739
  },
  {
    "x": 1699228800000,
    "y": 0.738
  },
  {
    "x": 1699315200000,
    "y": 0.747
  },
  {
    "x": 1699401600000,
    "y": 0.702
  },
  {
    "x": 1699488000000,
    "y": 0.701
  },
  {
    "x": 1699574400000,
    "y": 0.703
  },
  {
    "x": 1699660800000,
    "y": 0.685
  },
  {
    "x": 1699747200000,
    "y": 0.668
  },
  {
    "x": 1699833600000,
    "y": 0.657
  },
  {
    "x": 1699920000000,
    "y": 0.621
  },
  {
    "x": 1700006400000,
    "y": 0.556
  },
  {
    "x": 1700092800000,
    "y": 0.541
  },
  {
    "x": 1700179200000,
    "y": 0.564
  },
  {
    "x": 1700265600000,
    "y": 0.566
  },
  {
    "x": 1700352000000,
    "y": 0.558
  },
  {
    "x": 1700438400000,
    "y": 0.558
  },
  {
    "x": 1700524800000,
    "y": 0.556
  },
  {
    "x": 1700611200000,
    "y": 0.526
  },
  {
    "x": 1700697600000,
    "y": 0.515
  },
  {
    "x": 1700784000000,
    "y": 0.521
  },
  {
    "x": 1700870400000,
    "y": 0.529
  },
  {
    "x": 1700956800000,
    "y": 0.545
  },
  {
    "x": 1701043200000,
    "y": 0.537
  },
  {
    "x": 1701129600000,
    "y": 0.55
  },
  {
    "x": 1701216000000,
    "y": 0.569
  },
  {
    "x": 1701302400000,
    "y": 0.584
  },
  {
    "x": 1701388800000,
    "y": 0.608
  },
  {
    "x": 1701475200000,
    "y": 0.629
  },
  {
    "x": 1701561600000,
    "y": 0.669
  }];
            const saledata = [{
    "x": 1697842800000,
    "y": "147746"
  },
  {
    "x": 1697929200000,
    "y": "130250"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698015600000,
    "y": "104664"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698102000000,
    "y": "100406"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698188400000,
    "y": "151495"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698274800000,
    "y": "131127"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698361200000,
    "y": "133737"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698447600000,
    "y": "127386"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698534000000,
    "y": "113109"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698624000000,
    "y": "95932"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698710400000,
    "y": "99510"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698796800000,
    "y": "144000"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698883200000,
    "y": "119658"
  },
  {
    "x": 1698969600000,
    "y": "111486"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699056000000,
    "y": "108381"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699142400000,
    "y": "96228"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699228800000,
    "y": "74594"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699315200000,
    "y": "73836"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699401600000,
    "y": "118380"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699488000000,
    "y": "101331"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699574400000,
    "y": "100519"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699660800000,
    "y": "102802"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699747200000,
    "y": "88036"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699833600000,
    "y": "72038"
  },
  {
    "x": 1699920000000,
    "y": "80203"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700006400000,
    "y": "144604"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700092800000,
    "y": "101407"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700179200000,
    "y": "91762"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700265600000,
    "y": "96331"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700352000000,
    "y": "84467"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700438400000,
    "y": "66007"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700524800000,
    "y": "69887"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700611200000,
    "y": "138652"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700697600000,
    "y": "111720"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700784000000,
    "y": "108708"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700870400000,
    "y": "101870"
  },
  {
    "x": 1700956800000,
    "y": "99798"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701043200000,
    "y": "72229"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701129600000,
    "y": "71358"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701216000000,
    "y": "102909"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701302400000,
    "y": "87627"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701388800000,
    "y": "89769"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701475200000,
    "y": "93981"
  },
  {
    "x": 1701561600000,
    "y": "78223"
  }];

            var options = {
                series: [{
                name: 'Sold units',
                type: 'column',
                data: saledata
            }, {
                name: 'Price',
                type: 'line',
                data: pricedata
            }],
                chart: {
                id: "chart2",
                height: 350,
                type: 'line',
                toolbar: {
                        autoSelected: 'pan',
                        show: false
                    }
            },
            tooltip: {
                    theme: 'dark',
            },
            colors: [ "#333", '#F44336'],
                stroke: {
                    width: 3
                },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            fill: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
            markers: {
                size: 0,
                strokeColors: '000',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                hover: {
                    ssize: 4
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        colors: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                }
            },
            yaxis: [{
                    tickAmount: 3,
                    opposite: true,
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            colors: ["#FFFFFF"]
                        },
                        formatter: function(val, index) {
                            return val.toFixed(0);
                        },
                    },
                    max: 500000,
                  },
                  {
                    tickAmount: 3,
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            colors: ["#FFFFFF"]
                        },
                        formatter: function(val, index) {
                            return "$" + val.toFixed(2);
                      },
                    },
                    max: 1,
                  }
                ],
            grid: {
                borderColor: "#333"
            }
            };

            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();
        
            var optionsLine = {
                series: [{
                name: 'Sold units',
                type: 'column',
                data: saledata
            }, {
                name: 'Price',
                type: 'line',
                data: pricedata
            }],
            chart: {
                id: 'chart1',
                height: 200,
                type: 'area',
                brush:{
                    target: 'chart2',
                    enabled: true
                },
                selection: {
                    enabled: true,
                    xaxis: {
                        min: new Date('25 Oct 2023').getTime(),
                        max: new Date('30 Oct 2023').getTime()
                    },
                    fill: {
                        color: '#F44336'
                    }
                },
            },
            colors: ['#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF'],
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tooltip: {
                enabled: true
                },
                labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: "#FFFFFF"
                }
                }
            },
            yaxis: [{
                opposite: true,
                labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: "#ffffff"
                },
                formatter: function(val, index) {
                            return val.toFixed(0);
                        },
                },
                max: 500000,
            },
            {   
                labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: "#ffffff"
                },
                formatter: function(val, index) {
                            return "$" + val.toFixed(2);
                        },
                },
                max: 1,                
            }
            ],
            grid: {
                show: false  // Hide horizontal grid lines
            }
            };

            var chartLine = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chartline"), optionsLine);
            chartLine.render();
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #1c1c1c;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="chartline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with ApexCharts itself, and a [pull request has been made to fix it.](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/pull/3566) The PR was made over a year ago and has yet to be merged, so the issue still persists. There seems to be no workaround for this issue at this time.